# Validating form controls before inserting to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to insert the records into the database(MySQL) but before insertion i want to validate the form fields whether they are filled by users or not, It must be validate `onclick` of submit button and i am inserting the records using the annotation method which is related to a java file so, when i am trying to insert the records using spring annotation method and validating the records in JavaScript it gives me the following Error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

### My javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateFields()
    {
        var c_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtClinicName.value;
        var p_no = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtPhone.value;
        var st_address = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtStreetAddress.value;
        var state = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtState.value;
        var city = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCity.value;}
        var zip_code = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtZipCode1.value;
        var f_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPFName.value;
        var l_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPLName.value;
        var email = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtEmail.value;
        var cell_no = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCellPhone.value;
        var u_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtUserName.value;
        var pass = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtPassword.value;
        var c_pass = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtConfirmPassword.value;

        if(c_name == "" || c_name == null)
        {
            alert("Clinic name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(p_no == "" || p_no == null)
        {
            alert("Phone number can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(st_address == "" || st_address == null)
        {
            alert("Street address can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(state == "" || state == null)
        {
            alert("State can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(city == "" || city == null)
        {
            alert("City can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(zip_code == "" || zip_code == null)
        {
            alert("Zip code can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(f_name == "" || f_name == null)
        {
            alert("First name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(l_name == "" || l_name == null)
        {
            alert("Last name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(email == "" || email == null)
        {
            alert("Email can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(cell_no == "" || cell_no == null)
        {
            alert("Cell number can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(u_name == "" || u_name == null)
        {
            alert("User name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(pass == "" || pass == null)
        {
            alert("Password can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(c_pass == "" || c_pass == null)
        {
            alert("Confirm password can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

My mapping method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registerclinic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerclinicdbconnection(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException 
{
    String clinic_name = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtClinicName");
    long phone_no = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtPhone"));
    String street_add = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtStreetAddress");
    String state = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtState");
    String city = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtCity");
    int zip_code = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtZipCode1"));
    String first_name =  req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPFName");
    String last_name =  req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPLName");
    String email = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtEmail");
    long cell_phone = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtCellPhone"));
    String user_name = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtUserName");
    String password = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtPassword");
    String c_password = req.getParameter("ctl00$cphMaster$txtConfirmPassword");


    // Inserting records to register the clinic by making connection with database.
    String queryText = "insert into registerclinic(clinicname,phone,streetadd,state,city,zipcode,firstname,lastname,email,cellphone,username,password) values('"+clinic_name+"','"+phone_no+"','"+street_add+"','"+state+"','"+city+"','"+zip_code+"','"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+email+"','"+cell_phone+"','"+user_name+"','"+password+"')";
    try
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clinicmanagement","root","dipak");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        stat.executeUpdate(queryText);
        System.out.println("Record has been inserted");
        stat.close();
        con.close();
        return "success";
    }catch(Exception ea)
    { 
        System.out.println("Exception Occured.."+ ea);
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code you have

Comment: This is onsubmit of my form--->  <body>
 <form  id="formregisterclinic" name="formregisterclinic" onsubmit="return validateFields()" method="post"> @Pindo

Comment: please post the code of `validateFields()`method

Comment: thank you for your reply @pindo

Comment: Why are you parsing all the fields on your own?  Why not use form binding feature of Spring?  Search for it, it will save you time and headache of figuring out data mismatch issues.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion @manish

Answer (score 0):

seems as though you don't have a return true at the end of your `validateFields()` method

try below:

```
function validateFields()
    {
        var c_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtClinicName.value;
        var p_no = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtPhone.value;
        var st_address = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtStreetAddress.value;
        var state = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtState.value;
        var city = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCity.value;}
        var zip_code = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtZipCode1.value;
        var f_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPFName.value;
        var l_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCPLName.value;
        var email = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtEmail.value;
        var cell_no = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtCellPhone.value;
        var u_name = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtUserName.value;
        var pass = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtPassword.value;
        var c_pass = document.formregisterclinic.ctl00$cphMaster$txtConfirmPassword.value;

        if(c_name == "" || c_name == null)
        {
            alert("Clinic name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(p_no == "" || p_no == null)
        {
            alert("Phone number can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(st_address == "" || st_address == null)
        {
            alert("Street address can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(state == "" || state == null)
        {
            alert("State can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(city == "" || city == null)
        {
            alert("City can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(zip_code == "" || zip_code == null)
        {
            alert("Zip code can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(f_name == "" || f_name == null)
        {
            alert("First name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(l_name == "" || l_name == null)
        {
            alert("Last name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(email == "" || email == null)
        {
            alert("Email can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(cell_no == "" || cell_no == null)
        {
            alert("Cell number can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(u_name == "" || u_name == null)
        {
            alert("User name can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(pass == "" || pass == null)
        {
            alert("Password can't be blank");
            return false;
        }
        else if(c_pass == "" || c_pass == null)
        {
            alert("Confirm password can't be blank");
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it still displaying the same error @Pindo

Comment: Error--------->HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: i also want to know whether the post method of form will call first or the javascript, beacause my connectivity code reside in java file which is depend on the annotation method so, i want to execute the script first to validate the fields and then connectivity

Comment: @D.Misal the java class is expecting a Number but you have passed a string to it. so please format it correctly using `int i = Integer.parseInt(input);`

Comment: Number ?? for what ?? @Pindo

Comment: and where i have to format it in script or java file ?

Comment: @D.Misal check in your mysql which column is expecting a number or is formatted as a number. you format in in the Java file

Comment: is there any other output after the error code indicating what line is at fault eg. `NumberFormatException.java:65`